# Call the object inside the class using the user input

Tags: c#, class, object, variables, syntax

I want to write a simple code to get the user input and get it from a class. Because of the large number of objects in the class I do not want to use if or switch, tell me how can I do this Like the following code or Suggest a simple code to me , when i use this code it tell me identifier expected

```
public class Rates
{
    public double IRR { get; set; }
    public double ISK { get; set; }
    public double JEP { get; set; }
    public double JMD { get; set; }//my object are more
    public double JOD { get; set; }
    public double JPY { get; set; }
    public double KES { get; set; }
    public double KGS { get; set; }
    public double ZWL { get; set; }
}
public class RootObject_1
{
    public string disclaimer { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public int timestamp { get; set; }
    public string @base { get; set; }
    public Rates Rate { get; set; }
}
public void Main(string args)
{
 string json_mosavab = (new WebClient()).DownloadString("my link");
 var root1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject_1>(json_mosavab);

string a = "IRR";//For example, the user input is IRR 
Console.WriteLine("IRR IS :" + root1.Rate.(a));//MY error is here
//I wantmy code to work this way
Console.WriteLine("IRR IS :" + root1.Rate.IRR);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Console.WriteLine("IRR IS :" + root1.Rate.GetType().GetProperty(a).GetValue(root1.Rate, null));
```

or similarly:

```
Console.WriteLine("IRR IS :" + typeof(Rates).GetProperty(a).GetValue(root1.Rate, null));
```

In the above code, first you are specifying the type of your object using:

```
root1.Rate.GetType()
```

or

```
typeof(Rates)
```

Next, by calling `GetProperty`, you specify the property name you are going to access, as it can be seen, the input of this method is a `string` and therefore it's what a user can enter. Finally, using the `GetValue` method you specify the object that you want to the get the value of the specified property from.